# Is it possible to receive audio from microphone over Bluetooth and play it from device?

Tags: java, android, audio, bluetooth, inputstream

Android question:

Is there any way I can use a Bluetooth microphone to live stream audio speech and play the audio real-time through the speakers of my phone ?

NOTE: I am aware that there is concepts of Sink and Source in such streaming - is this also the case, as my microphone takes the role of a Source and my smartphone the role of a Sink? Or is this a whole different scenario altogether?

I am also aware there typically are used two different kinds of Bluetooth Profiles: Advanced Audio Distribtion Profile (A2DP) and Handsfree-Headset Profile (HFP).
I'm guessing then only A2DP is relevant in this situation as it regards audio streaming and HFP is used only for heands-free phonecalling, right?

The idead is I would be able to speak through a Bluetooth microphone and then hear the speech real-time through the speakers of my phone - like a one-way radio system ;-)

I am not looking for a complete code or anything, merely an answer to whether this is acutally possible? (And then a maybe a fingers-point in the right direction).

Sincerely thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, Classic BT allows bidirectional conversation.

I have not tried this way but of-course you can try changing in-built Audio profile at time you need.

Please give it a hit and let me know in case it works for you.

Cheers!
Vivek

Comment: "you can try changing in-built Audio profile" - I'm not sure I follow.
Do you mean I should try and re-write the A2DP BT Profile?

Comment: No. Right now I am also working over Classic BT and BLE modules. While working over the recorder functionality I found that there some Audio profile that needs to be changed in order to record from BT microphone. So here what I am trying to say is that you may check for some of change in those profile. If that works then please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: Isn't the only changes in the profiles those coming from the Bluetooth Special Interest Group (SIG) ? How can I personally make changes in the profiles?

Also, you're implying I need to record the audio in order to play it?
Can I not just play the audio directly from input to output without recording it ?

Comment: See that's what I am trying to say... Recording audio via BT microphone works well. I am not sure if BT microphone audio can be streamed directly. For that you may try changing audio streaming profiles (if any). Like I say BT microphone audio is directly streamed via call. So hopefully there might be some public API's that can help you. This is just a suggestion not the solution. Still I am seeing for this.

Comment: Ah, okay I see. Thanks, and thank you for your patience!